# findOne() returning all values instead of one

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am working on an endpoint with nodejs/express and mongoose. The endpoint should return only the found ID like this:

```
{
    "id": 3000,
    "group": 3,
    "title": "",
    "start_time": "2023-07-31T11:00:00.000Z",
    "end_time": "2023-07-31T20:00:00.000Z",
    "category": "green"
}
```

However, when I tested (localhost:3000/api/one/3000) it returns all the values that belong to the users instead of just one:

```
{
    "_id": "658",
    "schedule": [
        {
            "events": [
                {
                    "id": 3000,
                    "group": 3,
                    "title": "",
                    "start_time": "2023-12-01T11:00:00.000Z",
                    "end_time": "2023-12-01T20:00:00.000Z",
                    "category": "green",
                },
                {
                    "id": 3001,
                    "group": 3,
                    "title": "",
                    "start_time": "2023-12-02T11:00:00.000Z",
                    "end_time": "2023-12-02T20:00:00.000Z",
                    "category": "green",
                },
                {
                    "id": 3002,
                    "group": 3,
                    "title": "",
                    "start_time": "2023-12-03T11:00:00.000Z",
                    "end_time": "2023-12-03T20:00:00.000Z",
                    "category": "green",
                },
                {
                    "id": 3003,
                    "group": 3,
                    "title": "",
                    "start_time": "2023-12-04T11:00:00.000Z",
                    "end_time": "2023-12-04T20:00:00.000Z",
                    "category": "green",
                },
                {
                    "id": 3004,
                    "group": 3,
                    "title": "",
                    "start_time": "2023-12-07T11:00:00.000Z",
                    "end_time": "2023-12-07T20:00:00.000Z",
                    "category": "green",
                }
]
        }
    ]
}
```

This is the mongo schema:

```
import mongoose, { model, Schema } from "mongoose";

const eventSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  id: Number,
  group: Number,
  title: String,
  start_time: Date,
  end_time: Date,
  category: String,
});

const individualSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: String,
  events: [eventSchema],
});

const ScheduleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  schedule: [individualSchema],
});

export default model("Schedule", ScheduleSchema);
```

This is the function which I think there is something missing on the findOne():

```
export const getById = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const id = req.params.id;
    const found = await ScheduleSchema.findOne(
      { "schedule.events.id": id },
      { "schedule.events.$": 1 }
    );

    res.json(found);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    console.error(error);
  }
};
```

how can I fix it so it only return the given id?

Comment: I dont think, mongoDB has a way to directly support projecting a single element from a nested array in a document. You might wanna try using ```aggregate```, like this maybe
```await ScheduleSchema.aggregate([
  { $unwind: "$schedule" },
  { $unwind: "$schedule.events" },
  { $match: { "schedule.events.id": id } },
]);
```
and then use ```project``` to  get the matched document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may like something with aggregation like this perhaps:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{
 "$match": {
  "schedule.events.id": 3000
 }
},
{
"$project": {
  "schedule": {
    "$map": {
      "input": "$schedule",
      "as": "s",
      "in": {
        "events": {
          "$filter": {
            "input": "$$s.events",
            "as": "e",
            "cond": {
              "$eq": [
                "$$e.id",
                3000
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
   }
  }
 },
 {
 "$replaceRoot": {
   "newRoot": {
     $mergeObjects: "$schedule"
     }
    }
  },
  {
   "$replaceRoot": {
     "newRoot": {
      $mergeObjects: "$events"
    }
   }
  }
 ])
```

Explained:

1. Match the document having at least one nested object with id=3000
2. map/filter only the matched nested object with id=3000
3. flattent the object with 2x replaceRoot so you get just the nested object

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/DpfwOmGCztb)